# No suitable injection token for parameter 'basePath' of class 'HttpService'

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular12

I am working on a angular project.

I tried multiple inheritance.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoreStaffDesignationService extends StoredDataService<IStoreStaffDesignation> {

  constructor(
    public override http: HttpClient,
    ) {
    super('staff-designation', http);
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StoredDataService<T> extends HttpService<T> {

  constructor(public subPath: string, public override http: HttpClient) {
    super('store' + '/' + subPath, http);
    this.subPath = subPath;
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpService<T> {
    protected baseUrl: string;
    protected basePath: string;
    http: HttpClient;

    constructor(basePath: string, http: HttpClient) {
        this.baseUrl = `${environment.BASE_URL}`;
        this.basePath = basePath;
        this.http = http;
    }
}
```

I got complie failed with

error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'subPath' of class 'StoredDataService'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'basePath' of class 'HttpService'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

What is the mistake in my code?

Any one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Error mean angular not know how can resolve instance for this variable as it not registered in DI Container or Provider

to solve issue you need to create InjectionToken

```
export const stringInjector = new InjectionToken<any>('stringInjector');
```

and use new injector token in contructor

```
constructor(@Inject(stringInjector) public subPath: string, public override http: HttpClient) {
 }
```

check link here for more details
https://angular.io/errors/NG2003